# Trying to load a file when a Tab button is clicked

Tags: c#, tabs, controls

I'm trying to load and display a file (in a RichTextBox). When I click on a Tab with

```
private void tabControl1_selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBoxMotd.LoadFile(pfad + eskalation);
}
```

it doesn't update the file when the tab is clicked.

Comment: Did you wire up the event, or just write the method?

Comment: What do you get from `pfad + eskalation`? Use the [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0) method instead to get a valid path. ex. `richTextBoxMotd.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(pfad, eskalation));`

Answer (score 0):

Path and Eskalation is use to easy Change the Source of the Files.

[Variablen für PFad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7Ien.png)

[Methode zum Laden des Inhaltes beim Klicken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S7p6.png)

Butit wont change the Content when i Click on the Tab Page
[Settings of tabpage 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY0ji.png)

When i start the Programm it works fine so far with

[Code at start of the Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6KH7.png)